# What is the best way to keep track of the database log (insert, update, delete etc) in WCF?

Tags: c#, database, wcf, logging, log4net

From couple of days, I am looking for the way by which I can keep track of all the records inserted, updated, deleted, Which params are affected, which table, what time, values of params etc in WCF (C#).
I came up with Log4Net but, I don't know how to keep track of all this info in that. 
Is there any way to do that?

Comment: It depends entirely on how you're currently accessing the database, no data on which you have bothered to include in your question. Are using an ORM? They usually have logging capability built in. Or are you using ADO.Net, or ...?? Do you have a data abstraction layer where you can intercept commands and log the details? What database are you logging to anyway?

Comment: Yeah, I have a data abstraction layer where I am calling stored procedures to insert, update, delete etc. I am using SQL Server 2012.